# Read application configuration from Sparkcontext Object

Tags: apache-spark

I am developing a Spark application using pyspark shell.

I kickstarted the iPython notebook service using the command below, see [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/) how I created the profile:

```
IPYTHON_OPTS="notebook --port 8889 --profile pyspark" pyspark
```

Based on the documentation, there is a `sc` spark context object already created for me with some default configuration.

> "In the PySpark shell, a special interpreter-aware SparkContext is
>   already created for you, in the variable called sc. Making your own
>   SparkContext will not work."

I basically have two questions here:

(1) How can I get a summary of the configuration for the default `sc` object? 
I want to know how much memory has been allocated, how many cores I can use...etc. However, I only found a method called `getLocalProperty` for object sc from [pyspark API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/api/python/pyspark.context.SparkContext-class.html#setLocalProperty) without knowing what is the key argument that I should call.

(2) Is it possible to modify the sparkcontext working with iPythonnotebook. If you cannot modify the configurations once you started the iPython notebook, if there a file somewhere to configure the sc somewhere?

I am fairly new to Spark, the more information(resource) you can provide, the better it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to use pyspark: you can import the pyspark classes and then instantiate the SparkContext yourself

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
```

Set up your custom config:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)
# set values into conf here ..
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

You may also want to look at the general spark-env.sh

conf/spark-env.sh.template # copy to conf/spark-env.sh and then modify vals as useful to you

eg. some of the values you may customize:

```
# Options read when launching programs locally with
# ./bin/run-example or ./bin/spark-submit
# - HADOOP_CONF_DIR, to point Spark towards Hadoop configuration files
# - SPARK_LOCAL_IP, to set the IP address Spark binds to on this node
# - SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS, to set the public dns name of the driver program
# - SPARK_CLASSPATH, default classpath entries to append
```